# Ways to reduce CPU usage while using PhantomJS/CasperJS

Tags: phantomjs, cpu-usage, casperjs

Am using PhantomJS and CasperJS for screenscraping and stuff. The issue which I am facing is that its taking too much CPU usage which makes me feel it might not be that scalable. Are there any ways to reduce CPU usage for the same. Some of which I can think of are:

1) Disable image loading 
2) Disable js loading

Also I want to know if python is more light(in terms of CPU usage) than phantom for the scraping purpose.

Comment: What are you scraping if you wouldn't need images to load?? Use curl or wget then

Comment: I need to use casper/Phantom only... I am looking for ways to minimize cpu usage in it

Answer (score 0):

Why CasperJS / PhantomJS only? Are you scraping websites that load content with JavaScript? Any tool that doesn't run a full webkit browser will be more lightweight than one that does.

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `wget` or `curl` on linux systems to dump webpages to files / stdout. There are many libraries that can handle & parse raw HTML such as  [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) for NodeJS.

Still want some form of scripting? Because you mentioned python, there is a tool called [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) that does just that without running webkit. It's not as powerful as Casper / Phantom, but it allows you to do a lot of the same things (filling out forms, clicking links, etc) with a much smaller footprint.

Comment: +1 from me, I don't know why this should be downvoted. Yes, this does not help decrease Phantom's CPU usage (which I'd really love to do since I need JS to load) but it's still a good answer and OP shouldn't use phantom when there's no need for it. That's like asking how to drill a hole in a wall with a hammer and downvoting someone suggesting to use a drill.

Answer (score 0):

After 5 and a half years I don't think you are having this issue anymore, but if anyone else stumbles across this problem, here's the solution.

After finishing scraping, quit the browser by typing `browser.quit()`, browser being the name of the variable you set.

Comment: That is a good way to circumvent a big memory leak (restarting the browser every once in a while), but it won't help to reduce any CPU usage.