# CasperJS - CPU Usage problems

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, cpu-usage

Recently I've used CasperJS on my server for specific automation tasks.
And found a big problem - sometimes CPU jumps to over 30% usage.
I've played a lot with it and searched a lot for some information - and even found 2 different posts for this subject:

[Ways to reduce CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558714/ways-to-reduce-cpu-usage-while-using-phantomjs-casperjs)
and
[How to reduce CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424461/how-to-reduce-phantomjss-cpu-and-memory-usage?rq=1)

but unfortunately in both cases there are no relevant answers.

**Important** -
To reduce CPU usage I don't load images, and make all the tasks with the same Casper instance. 
But still CPU usage seems to be high.

Perhaps anyone has ideas how to improve it?
Or at least which functions shouldn't I use in CasperJS?

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with CasperJS, but rather a "problem" of the underlying browser: PhantomJS vs Slimer.js. I also don't know why you think 30% CPU usage is much. Browser automation scripts usually aren't written to behave exactly like a human would with all their pauses and such. I would expect somewhere between 50 and 100% of usage of a single core for an average script.

Comment: @Artjom First of all thanks for a fast reply. Second I do use **PhantomJS** - You think that's the source of my problem? If yes - how should I do it instead? About 30% CPU - it's a lot comparing to other languages which almost don't use CPU. In the future I would like to active few Caspers asynchronously - so to not kill my server I wanted to know ahead - how to reduce the CPU usage, if it's of course possible.

Comment: All languages consume 100% CPU (actually probably a single core). It can be less if the program isn't doing anything. The same goes for PhantomJS/CasperJS. If you're waiting (`casper.wait(100000)`), then you should see 100 seconds of low CPU usage. The question is why do you want to wait a lot.

Comment: @Artjom I don't want to wait, I want to reduce CPU usage. From my checks when I open htop I usually see 1~4% CPU usage, but when I use CasperJS it's consume at least 10% and sometimes jumps even over 30%. Maybe you know which functions are more 'expensive' in terms of CPU usage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is PhantomJS CPU (core) bound?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018331/is-phantomjs-cpu-core-bound)